# .NET can't deserialize nested structs?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, compact-framework

I'm running into issues getting C# (VS2008, Compact Framework, .NET is version 3.5 SP1) to successfully deserialize nested structs.  The problem only appears in CF when I'm running on the emulator for the mobile device (I'm using the "Pocket PC 2003 Second Edition" emulator), the exact same code running on my Windows box does not have the same problem.

Here's my code:

```
public struct Fred
{

    public string Name;
}

public struct Middle
{

    public Fred[] Freds;
}

public struct Top
{

   public Middle Middle;
   public Fred[] Freds;
}

public static void Test()
{

    Top top = new Top();
    top.Middle.Freds = new Fred[2];
    top.Middle.Freds[0].Name = "Fred20";
    top.Middle.Freds[1].Name = "Fred21";
    top.Freds = new Fred[2];
    top.Freds[0].Name = "Fred10";
    top.Freds[1].Name = "Fred11";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer x = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(top.GetType());

    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb))
    {
        x.Serialize(sw, top);
    }

    string xml = sb.ToString();
    string[] lines = xml.Split(new char[] { '\r', '\n' });

    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("   " + line.Trim());
    }

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xml));
   StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms);
   object o = x.Deserialize(sr);
   Debug.WriteLine("Deserialized into " + o);
   Top go2 = (Top)o;

   if (go2.Freds == null)
        Debug.WriteLine("   go2.Freds is null");
   else
       Debug.WriteLine("   go2.Freds[0].Name is \"" + go2.Freds[0].Name + "\"");

   if (go2.Middle.Freds == null)
       Debug.WriteLine("   go2.Middle.Freds is null");
   else
       Debug.WriteLine("   go2.Middle.Freds[0].Name is \"" + go2.Middle.Freds[0].Name + "\"");
}
```

When I run this, the XML it creates looks good:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Top xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <Middle>
      <Freds>
         <Fred>
            <Name>Fred20</Name>
         </Fred>
         <Fred>
            <Name>Fred21</Name>
         </Fred>
      </Freds>
   </Middle>
   <Freds>
      <Fred>
         <Name>Fred10</Name>
      </Fred>
      <Fred>
         <Name>Fred11</Name>
      </Fred>
   </Freds>
</Top>
```

but C# is unable to successfully deserialize this XML - the console output is this:

```
Deserialized into Top
go2.Freds[0].Name is "Fred10"
go2.Middle.Freds is null
```

xsd has similar problems:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="Top" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
<xs:element name="Top" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
<xs:complexType>
 <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
  <xs:element name="Middle">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Freds" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Fred" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                </xs:sequence>
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Have I just encountered a C# bug?  Or am I missing something obvious?

Note: It's not a problem with using the name twice, if I create a struct named George that is identical to Fred, and change the contents of Middle to public George[] George, the problem isn't any better.

Comment: Using your code, I get: 
go2.Freds[0].Name is "Fred10" | go2.Middle.Freds[0].Name is "Fred20". Which version of .NET are you developing in?

Comment: Can't reproduce this here either, using .Net 3.5 / VS 2008. One thing to note is that you shouldn't use `Encoding.ASCII` for XML as this will strip international characters. Use `Encoding.Unicode` or `Encoding.UTF8` instead, e.g.: `using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml))) using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms, Encoding.UTF8)) { }`

Comment: I've updated my post to include the version info, it's possible this is a drawback in the compact framework version of .NET ...

Comment: Well, your types don't make sense as `struct` objects in the first place.  They shouldn't be mutable, they don't represent logical values, you're boxing them quite a bit, etc.  They should simply be classes.

Comment: Yes, if I was creating this code, I would use classes.  Unfortunately, this is code I've inherited and it's in a library - and changes to that library are not in the scope of the current project, popping the hood on the library would significantly impact the scope and timeline ...

Comment: @Servy I don't believe there is much boxing/unboxing besides that one time in the XmlSerializer. ProtoBuf doesn't even seem to do this at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TLDR (for the skimmers): This post consist of two parts.

### Part 1: A quick intro to Protobuf. Attributes are used here.

### Part 2: The actual answer to the question: to configure serialization without modifying the inherited library

Ok, I'll give it a shot.

The problem seems to be that you're using the Compact Framework, which does not have the same serialization/deserialization capabilities as the full .NET framework. So we need some custom serialization here.

Going with the philosophy of the Compact Framework, my guess is that you also want something that performs well and has a small footprint. So I picked [Protobuf](https://github.com/google/protobuf) for the task (which is also [approximately 12 times faster than XmlSerializer](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/wiki/Performance))

You can install it by running this command:

```
Install-Package protobuf-net
```

Let's start with the easy way - by adding attributes to your model. 
Configuration without attributes comes next, as you pointed out that the original model can't/shouldn't be modified. This is only for illustration.

Decorated with the appropriate attributes, your model would look like this:

### Part 1: Configuration with attributes.

**I repeat, this part is only for illustration purposes - read on to "Configuration without attributes"**

```
[ProtoContract]
public struct Fred
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string Name;
}

[ProtoContract]
public struct Middle
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public Fred[] Freds;
}

[ProtoContract]
public struct Top
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public Middle Middle;

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public Fred[] Freds;
}
```

The only thing to note here is the usage of numbered members, called keys. It's essentially the same thing as giving them property names in the case of JSON or XML serialization, except this is the protobuf way to do it. You simply assign a unique integer value to each member within the same class, and most of the times you're done there.

For convenience let's add a simple Builder from which we can instantiate a `Top` which is similar to the one in your example:

```
public class TopTestBuilder
{
    public Top BuildDefaultTestTop()
    {
        var top = new Top
        {
            Middle = new Middle
            {
                Freds = new[]
                {
                    new Fred {Name = "Fred20"},
                    new Fred {Name = "Fred21"}
                }
            },
            Freds = new[]
            {
                new Fred {Name = "Fred10"},
                new Fred {Name = "Fred11"}
            }
        };

        return top;
    }
}
```

We can *serialize* it like this:

```
Top topIn = new TopTestBuilder().BuildDefaultTestTop();
string serialized;
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    Protobuf.Serializer.Serialize(stream, topIn);

    stream.Position = 0;
    var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
    serialized = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
// Output: "\nDC4\n\b\nACKFred20\n\b\nACKFred21DC2\b\nACKFred10DC2\b\nACKFred11"
```

And *deserialize* it like this:

```
Top topOut;
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
    writer.Write(serialized);
    writer.Flush();
    stream.Position = 0;

    topOut = Protobuf.Serializer.Deserialize<Top>(stream);
}
```

As you can see there is a little bit of plumbing for the `MemoryStreams`, but other than that it should look familiar to how other types of serialization work. Similarly, everything can just as well be accomplished by configuring a custom `TypeModel`, allowing serialization to be fully decoupled from the model.

### Part 2: Configuration without attributes

By default, Protobuf uses the attributes to define the `TypeModel` and then stores it in `ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Default`. This property is used when you call the static `Protobuf.Serializer` directly.
We can also define our own. It took some fiddling around (note to self: RTFM) to get it working but it turned out to be almost as simple:

```
var model = TypeModel.Create();

// The first parameter (maps to ProtoContractAttribute) is the Type to be included.
// The second parameter determines whether to apply default behavior,
// based on the attributes. Since we're not using those, this has no effect.
model.Add(typeof(Fred), false);
model.Add(typeof(Middle), false);
model.Add(typeof(Top), false);

// The newly added MetaTypes can be accessed through their respective Type indices.
//   The first parameter is the unique member number, similar to ProtoMemberAttribute.
//   The second parameter is the name of the member as it is declared in the class.
//   When the member is a list:
//     The third parameter is the Type for the items.
//     The fourth parameter is the Type for the list itself.
model[typeof(Fred)].Add(1, "Name");
model[typeof(Middle)].Add(1, "Freds", typeof(Fred), typeof(Fred[]));
model[typeof(Top)].Add(1, "Middle");
model[typeof(Top)].Add(2, "Freds", typeof(Fred), typeof(Fred[]));
```

Now all we have to do is change one line of code for both functions:

Serialize:

```
Top topIn = new TopTestBuilder().BuildDefaultTestTop();
string serialized;
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    model.Serialize(stream, top);

    stream.Position = 0;
    var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
    serialized = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Deserialize:

```
Top topOut;
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
    writer.Write(serialized);
    writer.Flush();
    stream.Position = 0;

    topOut = (Top) _model.Deserialize(stream, null, typeof (Top));
}
```

And it works just the same. Perhaps add a class to keep things organized - give it two public methods `Serialize` and `Deserialize`, and a private method `BuildTypeModel` (to call from the constructor and store in a field on the serializer?)

Your calling code would end up looking something like this:

```
var serializer = new CustomProtoBufSerializer();

var serialized = serializer.Serialize(someClassInput);

SomeClass someClassOutput = serializer.Deserialize(serialized);
```

One thing quickly became clear though - Protobuf hasn't been as thoroughly documented and tested as most JSON and XML serializers out there. This, along with the serialization results being non-readable to humans, could be a drawback in some situations. Other than that it seems like it's fast, lightweight and compatible with many different environments.

The absence of automatic type resolution bothered me a bit, so I went looking and found something that seems pretty interesting: [Protobuf T4 TypeModel Generator](https://github.com/JayCap/Protobuf-net-Patch-and-T4-TypeModel-Generator). I haven't been able to try it yet. If people are interested, I might do that later and update the answer with a more generic solution.

Let me know if you have any trouble getting it to work.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive info, unfortunately (as I said in my earlier comment) I'm trying really hard not to make major changes to the library in which this code resides.  If I were to "open up the hood", I would probably just make them all classes instead of structs (seems to avoid the C# bug)

Comment: There's no need to make any modifications to your library - that was after all the purpose of my answer. Otherwise I might as well have told you to decorate them with JSON or XML serialization contracts :) referring to this part in my post: "_Configuration without attributes comes next, as you pointed out that the original model can't/shouldn't be modified._ This is only for illustration.*"

Comment: Or.. do you mean to say that the serialization/deserialization part which is not working, is also part of your library? Because in that case you're probably out of luck, you won't get this to work with the built-in serializer in CF.

Comment: The definitions of the structures (which of course includes their nested-ness) is stuck in the library and reasonably unmodifiable.  The code I'm writing to serialize them into XML lives at the app level and I'm free to do whatever I want - but adding attributes would have to happen inside the library and therein lies the rub ...

Comment: You should actually *read* an answer before dismissing it. I added two separate big bold headers to my answer. See what it says below the second one.

Comment: Thank you for updating your answer, it was not at all clear in its original incarnation that the "part 2" did not require attribute changes (or any other library changes).  I think it's one of those things where it was obvious to you since you had been investigating protobuf, but not obvious to me that's what you meant.

Comment: You do have a point there. Some of my remarks were a little contextual and it would be hard for others to interpret them exactly as I intended. Lesson learned :) Anyway, I haven't been able to test it on Pocket PC Edition 2003 myself, so I'd love to know if it actually ended up working?