# Deserialising a list<struct>

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, json.net

I am trying to deserialise from json into a `List<struct>` - however my object is always null. The data types in the source JSON appear to be correct and my code does not throw any errors, so I am completely stumped as to why it does not work.

The class I am deserilaising into:

```
public class SystemStatusRules
{
    public struct EmailItem 
    {
        public int EmailSubject_Id;
        public bool IsSubject;
        public string Email_String; 
        public int StatusCode;
    }
    public List<EmailItem> EmailItems {get; set;}
}
```

My JSON:

```
{"EmailItems":[
    {"EmailSubject_Id":16,"IsSubject":true,"Email_String":"Cube Build Successful","StatusCode":0},
    {"EmailSubject_Id":17,"IsSubject":true,"Email_String":"Cube Build Failure","StatusCode":0}
]}
```

and finally, my deserialisation code:

```
[HttpPost]
public bool SetAllStatusRules(string ruleList )
{
    SystemStatusRules subjectRules =
        JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SystemStatusRules>(ruleList);
}
```

Just in case you need it, my serialising code:

```
objArray.push({ EmailSubject_Id: SubjectId, IsSubject: IsSubject,
                Email_String: EmailSubject, StatusCode: status });
objArray = { EmailItems: objArray };
var rulesJSON = JSON.stringify(objArray);
$.ajax({
    url: "Management/SetAllStatusRules",
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'ruleList='+rulesJSON,
        success: function (result) {
            MyResultFunction(result);
      }
  });
```

**Edit:**

It's something to do with me casting into an object. The following code has the subjectRules variable which is correctly populated. However ssr is null.

```
object subjectRules = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SystemStatusRules>(StatusRules);
SystemStatusRules ssr = (SystemStatusRules)subjectRules;
```

I Have no idea what is wrong, but deserialising into a var allows me to use the object with data as a workaround.

Comment: The `EmailItems` variables are fields. Add `{get;set;}` to each of them.

Comment: @EBrown: That should not make a difference here... They're _public_ fields so they should be populated correctly...

Comment: Still returns null if I change them to properties.

Comment: This [works fine for me](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aF6kRQ). Is this all of your code?

Comment: This is the only code that is executed. Unless there is something in my configuration that might affect it. I am using Newtonsoft.Json version=4.5.6. as that is the only one that is compatible with the version of MVC i am using.

Comment: You Json string, works for me with Json.Net 4.5.6. I just created console app and tested the code and it is de-serializing properly.

Comment: @ramiramilu: Agreed, here's an updated fiddle with that version: https://dotnetfiddle.net/AB14dO

Comment: Can you show us the code how you are serializing on client side and what the values which are being serialized?

Comment: So it does. Looks like I have some sort of nasty config issue.  I am using WebApi version 4.0.2, if that helps. I dont know what else could be causing this problem.

Comment: I can show you the serializing code, but the sample given is a capture from visual studio debug, so I dont know if it would help. I'm using JSON.Stringifigy and jquery ajax.

Comment: @NeilP: a little code formatting wont hurt. its an eyesore ;)

Comment: You're not using the compact framework by any chance?  because your problem sounds similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29348793/net-cant-deserialize-nested-structs

Comment: Nope, I can copy in my packages.config if it helps.

Comment: Side note: Do you have a serious reason to use structs?

Comment: I dont, I've changed my struct to a class and I'm still getting the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

## Answer

Here is [a working fiddle for you](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5bIzUF). **Edit:** You don't need `[FromBody]`. It just works. There's apparently nothing wrong with your code.

## View

```
<html lang="en">
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div class="container"></div>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){

    var container = $(".container");
    var objArray = [];

    objArray.push({ 
        EmailSubject_Id: "0", 
        IsSubject: "false",
        Email_String: "My Email", 
        StatusCode: "0" });

    objArray = { EmailItems: objArray };    

    var rulesJSON = JSON.stringify(objArray);
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.RouteUrl(new{ action="SetAllStatusRules", controller="Home"})',
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'ruleList='+rulesJSON                     
        })
    .done(function (d) { container.html(d); } );

});

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

## Controller

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace HelloWorldMvcApp
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [System.Web.Mvc.HttpGetAttribute]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
        public string SetAllStatusRules(string ruleList)
        {
            SystemStatusRules subjectRules = 
                JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SystemStatusRules>(ruleList);
            return subjectRules.EmailItems[0].Email_String;
        }
    }
}
```

## Model

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace HelloWorldMvcApp
{
    public class SystemStatusRules
    {
        public struct EmailItem
        {
            public int EmailSubject_Id;
            public bool IsSubject;
            public string Email_String;
            public int StatusCode;
        }

        public List<EmailItem> EmailItems { get; set; }
    }
}
```

## Console App (to test initially)

It appears to be something to do with your JavaScript POST and the payload that it delivers to your server. That's because the following works ([see fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Gd1bWW)):

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var json = @"
{'EmailItems':[
    {'EmailSubject_Id':16,'IsSubject':true,'Email_String':'Cube Build Successful','StatusCode':0},
    {'EmailSubject_Id':17,'IsSubject':true,'Email_String':'Cube Build Failure','StatusCode':0}
]}";
        var p = new Program();
        p.SetAllStatusRules(json);
    }

    public bool SetAllStatusRules(string ruleList)
    {
        SystemStatusRules subjectRules = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SystemStatusRules>(ruleList);
        Console.WriteLine(subjectRules.EmailItems.Count.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(subjectRules.EmailItems[0].Email_String);
        return true;
    }
}

public class SystemStatusRules
{
    public struct EmailItem
    {
        public int EmailSubject_Id;
        public bool IsSubject;
        public string Email_String;
        public int StatusCode;
    }
    public List<EmailItem> EmailItems { get; set; }
}
```